# Java valuable used as a part of identifier

Tags: java

I have a few rows like:

```
int a1;
int a2;
int a3;
...
```

And I want a cycle that uses an other integer to identify the specific 'a'.

For example:

```
int k;
```

`k` gets a random number then I use the `a'k'` valuable.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't need an array?

Comment: You'd like a class that contains int a1, int a2, int a3 etc... and a method to evaluate for i (at certain values), a'1', a'2' etc... correct?

Comment: Let's say those are more complicated then ints and it would be a promblem if I not store them 1 by 1.
rion18 Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have described this right in that you want to get a variable called

```
 variableName = "a" + anInteger;  // e.g. a1, a2, a3
```

Then you would need to use Java reflection

```
 Field field = yourClass.getClass().getField(variableName);
```

But you would need to do some sorting of the field based on type.  This seems complex for your level of Java though.

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible, but you can create an array like `int[] a = new int[20];`. Then you can access randomly the elements (from 0 to 19) with `a[randVariable] = 4;`.

Answer (score 2):

Given the names, you are probably looking for "the array way" (see Kayaman's answer):

```
int[] a = new int[10];
// ...
for (int i : a) { 
    // do something with 'i'
}
```

However, if you cannot declare those objects as an array, you can always create one just in time:

```
int a, b, c, d, e;
// ...
for (int i : new int[] {a, b, c, d, e}) { 
    // do something with 'i'
}
```

If you do not necessarily want to iterate all of them, but just a few:

- If they form a contiguous range (no empty spaces), declare them as an array, or build an array with the elements so you can, from then on, index using that array. This is similar to the approach in the above code samples.
- If they do not form a contiguous range (large, empty spaces), use a `Map` (if you need some kind of sorting and consistent ordering, use `TreeMap`; use `HashMap` otherwise)

In the second case, you are creating an array and initializing it at the same time, and then iterating its elements.

Comment: +1 that's nice as a last resort. Vastly better than a reflection approach.

Comment: Also, reflection would require a lot of code + exception handling, and would not work within methods.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do this in Java using reflection, assuming that your variables are fields of a class. But I'd advise against this as it makes your code brittle and is probably unnecessary.

Use an array instead if you can: e.g. `int[] a = new int[ToDo: size here];`

Answer (score 0):

You want to use arrays:

```
int a[] = new int[10];
int k = ....set a value....
... do something with .... a[k]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need reflection, building a String with the field name and then use Reflection API (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) to search for a field with name a1, a2, ...

Comment: Peter is struggling with arrays and you're pointing him to reflection? LOL

Comment: Indeed @tucuxi : that's the reason why I wrote "field". :)

Comment: There's no other way in Java to build a variable name dynamically.  If the question is flawed it's hard to justify criticism of the answer.